# Generating combinations of a list, all with the same length

Tags: python

Ok so if you use this you get the possible combinations of a list

```
stuff = [1, 2, 3]
for L in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
        print(subset)
```

And the result is

```
()
(1)
(2)
(3)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

Is there a way to change this so that the result will be

```
(0, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 0, 3)
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 0, 3)
(0, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
```

or another code that would do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the output order doesn't matter you could turn items on `stuff` to lists of length of 2 where the first number is 0 and use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> stuff = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(product(*([0, x] for x in stuff)))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 3), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 3), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 3)]
```